# Decide which table will be in from and which in join based upon condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query which I have written using [This Link](http://sqlhints.com/2013/09/07/joining-two-tables-without-any-common-column-between-them-sql-server/).

A [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/725d3/1/0) just in case the above link expires.

Sample code:

```
;WITH MentorTable (CommonId, MentorId, MentorName) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MentorId) AS CommonId,MentorId, MentorName
    FROM Mentor
)
,MenteeTable (CommonId, MenteeId, MenteeName) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MenteeId) AS CommonId,MenteeId, MenteeName
    FROM Mentee
)
SELECT MR.MentorId,MR.MentorName,ME.MenteeId,ME.MenteeName
FROM MentorTable MR
   LEFT OUTER JOIN MenteeTable ME ON MR.CommonId = ME.CommonId
```

I want to get data from five tables and join them without have any common column between them. The above query helps me achieve that. However, in the above query, the Mentortable (which is the from table) will always have more number of records than other tables so all records of other table will be visible with null on remaining rows.

However among my five tables, I dont know which table will have more number of records. I want my query to select from that table so that any rows from the rest of the tables wont be missed out. Also I have to change my join tables accordingly so that all the rest of the tables apart from the "from table" are joined. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to `full outer join` for this.  In your case, this looks like:

```
WITH MentorTable (CommonId, MentorId, MentorName) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MentorId) AS CommonId,MentorId, MentorName
    FROM Mentor
)
,    MenteeTable (CommonId, MenteeId, MenteeName) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MenteeId) AS CommonId,MenteeId, MenteeName
    FROM Mentee
)
SELECT COALESCE(MR.MentorId, ME.MentorId) as MentorId, MR.MentorName, ME.MenteeId, ME.MenteeName
FROM MentorTable MR FULL OUTER JOIN
     MenteeTable ME
     ON MR.CommonId = ME.CommonId;
```

However, this gets cumbersome as you add more conditions.  The `on` clause ends up looking like:

```
ON M5.CommonId = coalesce(M1.CommonId, M2.CommonId, M3.CommonId, M4.CommonId)
```

So, you can often handle this using `union all` and `group by`:

```
select CommonId, MAX(MentorName) as MentorName, MAX(MenteeName) as MenteeName
from ((select MR.CommonId, MR.MentorName, NULL as MenteeName from MentorTable MR) union all
      (select ME.CommonId, NULL, ME.MenteeName from MentorTable ME)
     ) t
group by CommonId;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, will test this and let u know

Comment: It worked, hats off to you man, I added more tables and tested and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot.